# How to play an audio file through Ionic on iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, ionic-framework, media

I am using cordovo media plugin to play an audio file on button click. It is working fine on Android but I don't understand the problem with iOS. Here is the code inside a controller:

```
 var url = '';

if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid() == true){
    url = "/android_asset/www/sound.wav";   
}else{
    url = "sound.wav";   
}




$scope.playAudio = function() {
    // Play the audio file at url
    var my_media = new Media(url,
        // success callback
        function () {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        },
        // error callback
        function (err) {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    );
    console.log("Play");
    // Play audio
    my_media.play();
}
```

I have spent many of my hours to figure out the problem, but I have no idea what has gone wrong. I will be genuinely thankful to you if you can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the error that Ios is giving you?

Comment: Is the file in www or <application>/documents/tmp?

Comment: @JurClerkx it just doesn't play the audio file.

Comment: @lan its in www folder

Comment: This was the problem with cordova media plugin, I have made few changes in the plugin for ios and now it is working.